# Magento Export page spinner keeps rolling

Tags: magento2, products, export, magento2.4.2

I am exporting products from native Magento features. After exporting it says `Message is added to the queue, wait to get your file soon. Make sure your cron job is running to export the file`. And the spinner keeps rolling. Cron is scheduled at every 5 min.

Sometimes spinner stops and I can download the CSV. But most of the time the spinner keeps rolling & rolling. I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

make sure nothing wrong in browser's console tab.

there are must be any js error is there. please fix that

Comment: I checked this already. No error on console.